# Is my method for computing $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2} = e^{-1/6}$ valid?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know that if $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exists and $f(x)$ is continuous at $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$, then we can interchange the limit with $f(x)$. That is,
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to a}g(x)).
$$

**So onto the limit in question:**

I'd like to show that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2} = e^{-1/6}.
$$

I start off by letting
$$
L = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}.
$$
Next, I apply the natural logarithm to both sides of the equation to give $$
\ln L = \ln\left(\lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}\right).
$$
But now, I would like to interchange the natural log with the limit on the right side of the equation. However, this seems not justified because I don't know, a priori, that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}$ exists and if it does exist, that the natural log is even defined at the limit (what if it's $0$ or negative?).

Thus, my method of interchanging the natural log with the limit seems circular. I need to assume the limit exists and is neither $0$ nor negative before proceeding with my computation.

**So here are my questions**: Is it actually justified to interchange the natural log with the limit in this type of computation? Is it commonplace and accepted to assume the limit exists when going about these types of computations? If not, can someone propsose an alternative method for computing this limit without using the epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: hint: consider expansion of sinx = x-1/6x^3+...

Comment: While solving you can assume that everything is defined and you can proceed. To be precise, if after all calculations you can return back and everything will be defined, then it's fine. For example, if you prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to +0}\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(\sin x/x)=-\frac{1}{6}$, then interchanging logarithm and limit is justified.

Comment: It's okay if $\lim (\frac {\sin x}x)^{\frac 1{x^2}}$ is $0$.  Then although $\ln 0$ is not defined $\lim_{w\to L} \ln w$ does (and is $-\infty$) we can use that instead.  And you know that it can't be negative because for all $x> 0$ we have $ (\frac {\sin x}x)^{\frac 1{x^2}}$.  If you worry just do cases. Case 1: the limit is $0$ if so then $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln (\frac {\sin x}x)^{\frac 1{x^2}} = -\infty$.  Does it?.  Case 2: Other wise $\ln L = \lim_{x\to 0}(\frac {\sin x}x)^{\frac 1{x^2}}$. What is that?

Comment: But the thing is... assuming the limit exist when it doesn't isn't going to *stop* us doing calculations.  And the result of our calculations will tell us if it *does* exist or not.

Comment: @fleablood: If I tried to find the "maximum of the function $f(x)=x^2$", then assuming that such a maximum exists, we can conclude that it must occur at $x=0$ since $f'(x)=0$ only when $x=0$. The assumption that such a maximum exists led us to make an incorrect conclusion. OP is worried that all he has shown is that "if the limit exists, then it must equal $e^{-1/6}$" rather than "the limit exists and is equal to $e^{-1/6}$".

Comment: "For example, if you prove that limx→+01x2ln(sinx/x)=−16, then interchanging logarithm and limit is justified. "  And if instean you prove $\lim \frac 1{x^2}\ln (\frac {\sin x}x) = \pm \infty$?  What then?  well that means $\lim (ImtiredoftypingMathJax) = 0$ or $\infty$.

Comment: @Joe but as the function is continuous and defined everywhere but $0$ the only way the limit *can't* exists is if it $\pm \infty$.  And if that were the case you *wouldn't* get the limit is $-\frac 16$. The $f(x) =x^2$ doesn't work as there are multiple ways $f'(x) = 0$ (if it is a min, or a max, or a saddle).  But if $\lim \ln x = \frac 16$ has only one way that is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formally you can compute $V=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\ln\left(\left(x^{-1}\sin x\right)^{x^{-2}}\right)$ and *then* say that $L=e^V$ with the theorem you've mentioned, applied to the function $e^x$ instead.

More colloquially, since $\ln:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ is a (strictly increasing) homeomorphism, you can say that for a positive function $f$ the quantity $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists as an extended real number if and only if $\lim_{x\to a}\ln f(x)$ exists, and if so they are related in the obvious way.

Comment: I was able to show this formally using your suggestion: Let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\ln\left(\left(x^{-1}\sin x\right)^{x^{-2}}\right)$. Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=\frac{-1}{6}$. The function $f(x)$ is obviously continuous at $x=\frac{-1}{6}$. By the theorem,  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x))=f(\frac{-1}{6}) = e^{-1/6}$. Am I correct? This seems rigorous as far as I'm concerned. My question is, what is the reason for your second paragraph in your answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can assume

$$L>0\implies\left(\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=L\iff \lim_{x\to0^+}\log(f(x))=\log(L)\right)$$ by continuity and monotonicity of the logarithm (in its domain).

Now you can evaluate

$$M=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log\left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)}{x^2}$$

and conclude for $L$. (Note that it works as soon as $M$ exists.)

Comment: Hi, is continuity and monotonicity being used to show that the natural log function is 1-to-1? If not, why is it necessary to state that it is monotonic?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts: monotonicity is required for $\iff$ to hold.

Answer (score 0):

I will use the follow identity

$$\left( \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right)^{1/x^2}=e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln \left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}=e^{\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{\ln \left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}}\right)}=e^{\left(\frac{\ln \left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}{x^2}\right)}$$
Hence using de L'Hopital rule for $x\to 0^+$,

$$\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\frac{x\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)}{x\sin \left(x\right)}}{2x}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{x\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)}{2x^2\sin \left(x\right)}\right)$$
Using again the same rule,

$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{-x\sin \left(x\right)}{2\left(2x\sin \left(x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)x^2\right)}\right)=\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(-\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{2\left(x\cos \left(x\right)+2\sin \left(x\right)\right)}\right)$$
Apply again the same rule,
$$=\lim _{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{-\cos \left(x\right)}{2\left(-x\sin \left(x\right)+3\cos \left(x\right)\right)}\right)=-\frac 16$$

Definitively the limit it is $e^{-\frac 16}$.

Comment: Actually , $$=e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln \left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}=e^{\left(\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{\ln \left(\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\right)}}\right)}\;.$$

Comment: @Angelo You're right....thank you for your advice....and I have not seen your answer -)

Comment: Have you already seen my answer ? Have you understood why I was said that actually it is not what the original poster asked ? I have upvoted you. If you do it too, I will thank you.

Comment: @Angelo Truly I have voted immediately all the users (also you) this afternoon you and the other users.

Answer (score -2):

Since $\;\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o\left(x^3\right)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin -x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{-\dfrac{x^3}6+o\left(x^3\right)}{x^3}=$

$\quad=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[-\dfrac16+\dfrac{o\left(x^3\right)}{x^3}\right]=-\dfrac16\;.$

Moreover , by letting $\;y=\dfrac{\sin x}x-1\;,\;$ we get that

$\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=\bigg[\big(1+y\big)^{\frac1y}\bigg]^{\frac y{x^2}}=\bigg[\big(1+y\big)^{\frac1y}\bigg]^{\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

Since $\;y=\dfrac{\sin x}x-1\;,\;$ it results that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\;y=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x-1\right)=1-1=0\;.$

From $\;(*)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\bigg[\big(1+y\big)^{\frac1y}\bigg]^{\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}=$

$\quad=\bigg[\lim\limits_{x\to0}\big(1+y\big)^{\frac1y}\bigg]^{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}=$

$\quad=\bigg[\lim\limits_{y\to0}\big(1+y\big)^{\frac1y}\bigg]^{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}}\!=e^{-\frac16}\;,$

hence ,

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=e^{-\frac16}\;.$

Comment: This is not really what the OP is asking.

Comment: He is asking a method for computing the limit $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}$$ but, since there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}},\;$ it follows that $$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}\;.$$

Comment: @Angelo But he isn't asking for an arbitrary method, but a very specific ones. While correct, yours is different.

Comment: @Angelo: OP asks "Is it actually justified to interchange the natural log with the limit in this type of computation?", hinting at a more general question about the validity of a method used to evaluate limits. The example he uses is just for illustration as far as I can see. (I did not downvote, but Yves makes a very valid point.)

Comment: The original poster wrote that he would like to show that $$\;\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\left(\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^{\frac1{x^2}}=e^{-\frac16}\;,\;$$ so it is not just an example for illustration, but it is what he actually wants to get.

Comment: Moreover my method is not different because I too am using the continuity of the function $\;f(u,v)=u^v\;$ on $\;\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb R\;$ in order to interchange it with the limit.